# Font Size Of Page Header Changing After Refreshing Page - Yii2

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap, yii2

I'm having Register/Login Page. After submitting page, it successfully go to another page. As soon i click 'back' button on browser, it comes to Register/Login page. But, font size of "Page Header" is not same as it was before submitting.

After pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> more than 2-3 times, 'Page-Header' appears correct.

I'm showing 2 screen shot. First One is before submitting. Second One is, Clicking 'Back' Button in browser.

- Before Submitting

[image]

- After Clicking 'Back' Button

[image]

You all can clearly see.. Page Header -> 'Register' & 'Login' is changed.

[NOTE: It not happens every time. But, i've seen this problem several times.]

[image]

[image]

Here, is my code.

```
<?php
use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\bootstrap\ActiveForm;
use yii\captcha\Captcha;

$this->title = 'Register';
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = $this->title;
?>
<div class="site-about">
    <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-6">
            <h1>Register</h1>
            .
            .
        </div>
        <div class='col-lg-6'>
            <h1>Login</h1>
            .
            .
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That seems a Yii2 bug, if none knows an answer try to post it in Yii's forum or open a Issue in their github

Comment: Ok Mr @Sageth. I'll Post This Issue In Their Github.

Comment: It simply looks like a font loading problem, you should check your network console...